# How to check a matrix postion value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, position

Given a matrix filled in with all its values, there's the need of pulling out data randomly in order to create a random matrix (intialized with null values each position). The issue lies while checking if a position (within the randomMatrix) is different from null, as shown below:

```
public void randomLogic(String[][] givenMatrix){   

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                int positioni = this.randInt(0, 1);
                int positionj = this.randInt(0, 1);
                int x = this.randInt(0, 3);
                int y = this.randInt(0, 2);            

             /*In here lies the reported issue while checking if empty. */
             while (!this.randomMatrix[x][y].isEmpty()) {
                    x = this.randInt(0, 3);
                    y = this.randInt(0, 2);
                    this.randomMatrix[x][y] = givenMatrix[positioni][positionj];
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried with the following: `while(this.randomMatrix[x][y] != null)` and the code breaks down right away. All the solving-logic work out as expected (because if I ommit that part it works with flaws but works) the only problem is that validation. Regardless of what position is being evaluated it always stops working.

Is there any other way of checking a matrix position value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to pull random values (and consequently, some will be repeated) from a givenMatrix OR do you want to specifically randomize the givenMatrix?

If it's the latter, I would approach it differently.
First of all, gather all values of the givenMatrix in one linear-array or list. 
Then, you can randomize this array, and you'll be left with a big array of rows*columns items, with all the values from the original matrix already randomized.

Then, you can systematically fill the new randomized matrix, taking each element of the array in order, till you complete each row and column of the new matrix.

I would choose this approach, because it's easier, and it will finish in a fixed number of steps; rather than filling random positions, because maybe you land 2 times in the same place to fill, and you'll have to randomize until you hit all the spots.

(Also, if you don't care of repeating the values for the new matrix, then instead of taking each element of the randomized array, you can simply pick a random position of this array each time)

Comment: Well, your point of view and the solution given is pretty good! I hadn't thought so and I guess It'd work better... although this method is just a part of the solution. The problem is, for instance: "Three matrixes are given so you'll randomize them into a new matrix, and there's no constraint of repeated values, that's why I didn't care about that". However, what you pointed out about avoiding repeated values is a good approach. I'll take everything into account :D thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared String[][] randomMatrix as a class level member variable? If you have declared the randomMatrix correctly then the isEmpty() and != null checks should work.

Comment: It's been declared within a helper class, and it's been initialized from another class which is the main. It's declared as follows:
    public int rows = 0;
    public int columns = 0;
    public String[][] randomMatrix = new String[rows][columns];
So, to fill these values I use its getters and seters so while debugging the randomMatrix has each value with a 'null'.

Comment: In the randomLogic(String[][] givenMatrix) method, you are accessing the randomMatrix using 'this' keyword. So I would assume you have it in the same class as the randomLogic method. Other ways could be that a) you declare randomMatrix in the randomLogic method itself and later return it. And, then use it to set the values.                                                              or b) pass another parameter String[][] randomMatrix to the randomLogic method, and later return the updated one.